# Under what circumstances are food banks financially necessary?

Tags: united-kingdom, social-welfare, poverty, food

In Britain, food banks are a politically polarising issue. Some people find their existence essential, whilst some claim the need is [drastically exaggerated](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2606573/Food-bank-charity-misleading-public-Claim-1m-need-food-parcels-just-self-promotion.html).

I am yet to make my mind up as I do not fully understand the circumstances around which they are implemented. In Britain, we have disability benefit, unemployment benefit, child tax credit and many other safety nets for disadvantaged people to pay for the things they need, so what purpose do food banks serve?

Are there any extenuating circumstances that justify their necessity?

Comment: "Some people find their existence essential, whilst some find them pointless and unnecessary."  please cite sources for these viewpoints.

Comment: @JamesK will do

Comment: @JamesK done. Though I did edit pointless and unnecessary to drastically exaggerated

Answer (score 10):

The primary proximate extenuating circumstance is that a person is needing to eat, while lacking the money to purchase food. While the mechanisms you list exist, they have a certain bureaucratic inertia in how changes of circumstance are processed, whereas [life tends to happen at its own speed](https://www.trusselltrust.org/what-we-do/real-stories/).

The Trussell Trust (a UK food bank provider) have put out a [report documenting the users of their Food banks](https://www.trusselltrust.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/07/OU_Report_final_01_08_online2.pdf) suggesting 39% of respondents to their survey were waiting on the result of a new benefit application.

Comment: I see. Good to know. I'll give it a read

Comment: However, could you elaborate on the nature of the "beurocratic inertia" you speak of?

Comment: @Charlie Simply the time between an application being made and money arriving in a form it can be spent (assuming the application is successful). Taking housing benefit as a (sub-optimal) example, the DWP statistics say applications currently take 21 calendar days to process https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/632362/hb-speed-of-processing-summary-jan-mar-2017.pdf

Comment: one would think they would have had the sense to create savings for such a situation

Comment: @Charlie Who is "they" in that sentence? There are some circumstances in which discretionary funds are available, but there are incentives to prevent fraud (to the possible damage of those in genuine need), whereas food banks tend down the "nobody left behind" path.

Comment: They is those using food banks. I'm a teenager and have enough money in my bank to live modestly for a good while with no income

Comment: @Charlie. Congratulations, you've been fortunate so far. Many other people aren't in the same situation: https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/corporate/four-out-of-10-adults-are-not-in-control-of-their-finances-new-strategy-launched-to-improve-uks-financial-capability

Comment: possibly, but not likely. I'm from bottom rung stock myself

Comment: @origimbo - and many people splash on purchases that aren't necessary instead of trying to save. Absolving people for poor decisions is popular these days but merely deepens the problem, by rewarding those who make poor decisions at the expense of those who don't

Comment: For those blaming food bank usage on laziness/stupidity: Usage has increased more than 400-fold in the last 10 years. There is no evidence poor people have become drastically *worse* at decision making in that time. The actual causes are complex but include sweeping changes in benefit payments and greater administrative delays, as [FullFact explains](https://fullfact.org/economy/why-are-more-people-using-food-banks/).

Answer (score 4):

Food banks are for emergency financial crises. You may think that living frugally is always possible with good planning but imagine:

Do you have enough money to cover a month rent, heating, electricity? water? Phone? Your kids need a new school uniform, your daughter needs new underwear, you have a debt on your credit card and another debt on the car, and then that car breaks down and you need to find another £300 to fix it. You go to Tesco, but your credit card is refused. The next benefit cheque is coming but your children need feeding today...  Emergency financial crises are real.

This is the kind of situation that Food Banks are intended to deal with. They are not a complete solution to poverty. This person needs help: debt and credit advice, basic financial planning advice. She probably needs to improve her education to get a job, or a better job. She may well not have the ability to help herself (frankly she isn't that bright, but that is no crime) but in the short term, the Food Bank means that she and her kids can eat this week, and moreover the food bank acts as a point of contact to help her access the financial support that she will need to eventually pull herself up.

Comment: So they are for people who have poor finance skills, don't possess the hindsight to create savings or have family or friends they can ask for help from? A phone (or a phone with modern features) is not an essential item. I see what you're saying, and it's a good answer so I'll upvote, but I have to say I strongly object to the validity of the situation

Comment: @Charlie A phone can be an essential item if you need it to do your job (e.g. many work from home telemarketing companies require you to provide your own phone). Similarly, car repairs can be an essential item if your livelihood is delivering pizza with your own car or being a Lyft driver. Also, often people are unaware of bank charges, or have accounts limits shut down due to a false positive fraud alert or a reduction in credit limit of which the person was unaware and had planned based upon. Shit happens in myriad ways & poverty creates "cognitive overload" that makes rational action hard.